# Is there a way to do a distributed file download over a Hadoop cluster?

Tags: performance, hadoop, apache-spark, download, cluster-computing

I want to download lots of data files for a machine learning project. These downloads take quite a long time and I would like to speed them up.

I have a Hadoop cluster, and I thought I may take advantage of that to get faster downloads. Is there anyway to distribute the file download over the cluster to improve the speed?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of files, and a sparkcontext available, you can just do `sparkContext.parallelize(fileList).foreach(downloadMethod(_))` and it will automatically distribute the downloading tasks over executors.

Answer (score 0):

You can add file details in the below format in a seperate metadata file like below before writing a map-reduce job,

file1 --> http://myorg.com/test1.txt

file2 --> http://myorg.com/test2.txt

file3 --> http://myorg.com/test3.txt

You can start a mapreduce code with LongWritable and Text as input from the above file. and inside the map() function, you can get the URL's in the form of values to the map function and write a code to hit these URL's and download these files using the regular java connection interface.

By this way, the load for downloading multiple files will be distributed across various mappers.

Comment: I will look into this. However, I am not familiar with writing MapReduce. I have been writing in Spark. Is there a similar way to do this in Spark?

Comment: Convert the above meta data file into an RDD and execute the download service in the executors.